# Queries for node groups?

Tags: neo4j, path, cypher

I have two groups of nodes:

```
1) n1 -rel-> n2 -rel-> n3 -rel-> n4
2) n5 -rel-> n6 -rel-> n7
```

Created with commands:

```
1) CREATE (n1 { id:'n1' })-[:rel]->(n2 {id:'n2' })-[:rel]->(n3 { id:'n3' })-[:rel]->(n4 {id:'n4'})
2) CREATE (n5 { id:'n5' })-[:rel]->(n6 {id:'n6' })-[:rel]->(n7 { id:'n7' })
```

What are queries to:

1) Find groups of nodes ordered by the longest path existing in a group?

2) Find groups of nodes ordered by the number of nodes that group contains?

3) Given any two node id's find all paths connecting them ?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? The only real difference I can see between the two "groups" is the number of nodes in between the beginning and ending. E.g. n1-rel->n2-rel->n3 could be considered part of the second group, no? The "rel" type is all the same between all nodes, and the nodes aren't making use of labels. There's nothing to really uniquely identify those two "groups". Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: This is just an example. In real case groups may be very different. Notwithstanding question is open.

Comment: Also, what's the difference between query 1 and query 2? Just descending ordering vs ascending, respectively?

Comment: Path length and number of nodes in a group is not one and the same thing. For example, a group may consist of 10 nodes all connected to a single root, where path length is 1 for all nodes.

Comment: Ok.  That's not clear from your question.  So it sounds like you're talking about your queries operating against arbitrary graphs (i.e. any graph at all).  Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, exactly the case.

Comment: Well, in #2, the "group" has to be delineated somehow, and it sounds like that's still a path, as there are a near-infinite number of patterns in which nodes can be "grouped".  A path joining them is only one type of "grouping" but it's the clearest given what you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Pathfinding even when specifying a begin and end node can be a costly.  If you're going to do it between "all nodes", that's downright expensive.

However...

1. `MATCH p = (n)-[*]-(m) 
   RETURN nodes(p)
   ORDER BY length(p) DESC`
2. Given your comment below, this might help:

   `MATCH p = (n)-[*]-(m) 
   WHERE ALL(x IN nodes(p) | x.id IN [<id1>, ..., <id_x>]) 
     AND m.id <> n.id
   RETURN nodes(p)
   ORDER BY length(p) DESC`
3. `MATCH p = (n {id: <id1>})-[*]-(m {id: <id2>})
   RETURN p`

But these are horribly, horribly expensive queries, and really, if you do use them, you'll want to put limits on both the number of results returned AND the max depth of the nodes/relationships.

Comment: Thanks! To answer 2) I will reformulate the question: How to find the longest path in a given group of nodes? For example, a group: n1 -> n2 -> n3 -> n4 -> n5 -> n6, n1-> n7 -> n8 The longest path is n1 -> .. -> n6 another shorter path n1 -> ... -> n8. So?

Comment: Updated answer. You should definitely test it, though, as I'm not 100% on it.

Comment: After testing in Neo4j Web server console: 1) does not return the longest pass, but only some partial passes between two nodes 2) does not work because I have no appriory knowledege of <id1>, ..., <id_x> in this case 3) works but also returns all partial passes between two nodes

Comment: 1. This query will do what you want it to based on what you've told me. Again, given the overly-vague/general description of what you want, it's not a lot to go on.  That query will order in descending order ALL paths between two arbitrary nodes.  2. And how am I supposed to know that? Given that you created the nodes the way you did, I had to make an assumption. Remove the "ALL" clause and leave the m.id <> n.id bit, or use id(m) <> id(n) 3. Again, you said ALL paths.